# jquery cycle - cannot reset pager by passing cycle('0')

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I have two tabs in my home page and each tab has one jquery cycle slider. It has pager controls, prev, next controls. The requirement is to open the other tab when the all the slides in the tab is played. and vice versa.

I achieved it through the following code in the after option:

```
after: function(curElement, nextElement, options, forwardFlag) {  
               if (options.currSlide == 4)   
                   {
                       $('#slider1 ul').cycle('pause');   
                       setTimeout(function(){          
                       $('#home-page-tabs').tabs('select', 1);       
                       $('#slider ul').cycle('resume').cycle('0');  
                       }, 10000);  
                   }
               },
```

NOw automatically the second tab is opened once the first tab slide completes, and it opens with the first slide. However the pager controls is not reset to first one. It shows wrong number. How can i make the pager to show the right number? That is 0?

Comment: Try removing the single quotes around `0`: `cycle(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing single quotes did the trick.